# How to change port group properties in vcenter,e.g., like blocking a specific port of virtual port group by MAC address

Tags: python, vcenter, pysphere

I want to write a script that accepts a virtual port group name and a MAC address, based on which I want to block a certain port of that Virtual Port Group. Is there any way of doing it using pysphere APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using ReconfigureDVPort_Task API.

```
    new_request = VI.ReconfigureDVPort_TaskRequestMsg()
    all_switches = self.server._get_managed_objects(MORTypes.DistributedVirtualSwitch, from_mor=nfmor)
    _this = new_request.new__this(all_switches.keys()[0])
    _this.set_attribute_type(all_switches.keys()[0].get_attribute_type())
    new_request.set_element__this(_this)
    port = new_request.new_port()
    setting = port.new_setting()
    blocked = setting.new_blocked()
    blocked.set_element_value(True)
    blocked.set_element_inherited(False)
    setting.set_element_blocked(blocked)
    port.set_element_key(required_port.Key)
    port.set_element_setting(setting)
    port.set_element_operation('edit')
    new_request.set_element_port([port])
    ret = self.server._proxy.ReconfigureDVPort_Task(new_request)._returnval
```